# Difference between start_key and start_token in Cassandra KeyRange

Tags: cassandra

I'm wondering what the difference is between the two listed here: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API10

I tend to use start_key more but am wondering what the word 'token' relates to in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link:

> The semantics of start keys and tokens are slightly different. Keys
>   are start-inclusive; tokens are start-exclusive. Token ranges may also
>   wrap -- that is, the end token may be less than the start one. Thus, a
>   range from keyX to keyX is a one-element range, but a range from
>   tokenY to tokenY is the full ring (one exception is if keyX is mapped
>   to the minimum token, then the range from keyX to keyX is the full
>   ring).

I've used tokens to scan all the rows within a CF without knowing any of these -- setting start token empty and end token empty (this is equivalent to what they say from tokenY to tokenY)

As far as tokens are concerned I couldn't find a valid usage for rows scanning if not the one to iterate over all the table but I guess this is due to the RandomPartitioner -- I guess that could be more helpful with OPP

HTH, Carlo

Comment: Thanks Carlo. Would you mind explaining what OPP is and what the difference between using empty keys vs using tokens

Comment: I've talked about "empty tokens", and is absolutely equivalent to say scan from TokenX to TokenX. Tokens are start exclusive. If you query a range from keyX to keyX, you'll get (if exists) 1 value, X. If you query a range from tokenX to tokenX cassandra will start retrieving the value next to X as first and will retrieve X as final value (it will retrieve the full ring).OPP=Order Preserving Partitioner -- with RP you can't know the result of scanning rows from tokenX to tokenY (they're randomly distributed), with OPP you can scan over ranges of your rows like you're using a traditional index.